# After Validations go to next fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app I want to go next fragment after validation of checkboxes and Edit text

- I wrote code for validation but not able to put logics to go to next fragment after pressing **Next** Button

**EXPLANATION**
Fragment contain two checkboxes, user have a choice to select either checkbox 1 or checkbox 2 or both
and for each checkboxes it contains Edit texts

so how can put logics so that it should validate and should go to next fragment

**EXAMPLE**

- If user checked only checkbox 1 so it should validate the Edit text and then go to next fragment after pressing next button
- Similarly if user checked only checkbox 2
- And last if user checked both checkBoxes so it should validate both the Edit Text specified with it and then after pressing next button it will go to next fragment

Note - Validation means here edit text should not empty or blank. And check box should not unchecked.

I hope i explained my doubt Clearly

Comment: what do you mean by `validate`? What validation should the EditText go through?

Comment: Validation means here edit text or check boxes should not black or empty @Rey

Comment: You need to provide more information about your current implementation. Otherwise no one will be able to provide you with an advice. The question is too generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            val EditText_1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et1)
            val EditText_2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et2)
    
            val CheckBox_1 = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.cb1)
            val CheckBox_2 = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.cb2)
    
            val Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.bt)
    
            Button.setOnClickListener {
                when {
                    CheckBox_1.isChecked && CheckBox_2.isChecked && EditText_1.text.isNotBlank() && EditText_2.text.isNotBlank() -> {
                        // Proceed To next fragment
                    }
                    CheckBox_1.isChecked && EditText_1.text.isNotBlank() -> {
                        // Proceed To next Fragment
                    }
                    CheckBox_2.isChecked && EditText_2.text.isNotBlank() -> {
                        // Proceed To next Fragment
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah, little bit like same as you give an example... i updated my question you can see if you get to know what i am saying then please help to solve this problem

Comment: Thanks a lot dude @Rey my problem solved from your answer :)